# How to use mix in Laravel Package development?

Tags: laravel

I am creating a custom laravel packages for inside company usage and I am trying to figure out how to work with the assets that this package requires.

I have `src/resources/js` where I have multiple `JS` and `CSS` files. I'm want to run `npm run watch` while developing the package so I could see the changes. After the patch/update is done I want to run `npm run production` that would save these files in `src/dist` where user can publish these to their public directory (if wanted) with this command in my `serviceProvider`:

```
    protected function registerAssets() {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__ . '/dist/' => public_path('/public/vendor/myPackage'),
        ], 'public');
    }
```

Now my question is how do I structure my `webpack` and my `blade` views to work with my logic so while running `npm run watch` the `mix()` function in my blade will load the assets from one directory and if I publish my package it will the assets from another directory?

Do I understand the logic correctly for package development with the assets?

Answer (score 2):

When you do `npm run watch` the view will get them from the same path, but it will just change their hash, so the cache can be removed. I think after you prepare them for production/dist use there won't be a need to use `mix()` anymore, because your package or the project using the package won't be recompiling them. For example when you add bootstrap.js to your project you just load the asset whenever is needed and you don't compile it.

When you publish or release you package, I think your views should be using the dist folder assets and while you develop it you should use mix. If the project using your package needs some asset in their own view, it should figure out the path for the dist published directory. You can also make your package configurable for where the assets are published and from where your views can load them. Another option would be to make a wrapper of the `mix()` function and also load assets depending on specific configuration. I hope this gives you some ideas on how to proceed depending on how the package will be used by others.